# Maven: Transitive Dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a library for some projects which relies on Spark and HBase.
So the POM of the library looks something link this:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.4</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
 ...
</dependencies>
```

And in the specific project that uses the central library (which is published on an internal Maven repository) I have this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This, however does not then automatically include the dependencies that the library itself has. Therefore I would need to copy the dependency section of the library POM into the application POM.

Do you have any advice what might be missing/wrong?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Did you need a `jar with dependencies` ?

Comment: you can run `mvn dependency:tree` maybe some dependencies are in conflict and an older version of a dependency gets selected than you assume

Comment: Please take a look to this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html . You should find answer there.